# How to plot a line with (x,y) points?

Tags: chart.js

Noob question, apologies, but reading through the docs it was not obvious, and doing the obvious thing is resulting all points on x==0 !?

Many thanks in advance!

My current code is

```js
new Chart(canvasId,{
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            datasets: [
                {
                label: 'Some Data',
                data: [
                    { x: 0, y: 2.344317674636841 },
                    { x: 9, y: 2.2913742065429688 },
                    { x: 19, y: 2.2962939739227295 },
                    { x: 29, y: 2.26206374168396 },
                    { x: 39, y: 2.2287118434906006 },
                    { x: 49, y: 2.1946732997894287 },
                    { x: 59, y: 2.192193031311035 },
                    { x: 69, y: 2.1846773624420166 },
                    { x: 79, y: 2.122765064239502 },
                    { x: 89, y: 2.1172447204589844 },
                    { x: 99, y: 2.125208616256714 },
                    ]
                },
            ]
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a line chart which uses a catagory scale by default for the x axes and as you can read in this section of the docs that does not work with integers https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.9.1/general/data-structures.html#object

So you will need to set `options.scales.x.type` to `'linear'`

Comment: Thanks, that worked!! Somewhere else I also found that changing it to "scatter" also works (but it sounds an odd configuration).

Comment: Reason changing it to scatter works is because it overwrites the x scale from it's default to linear